# Trying to use ExtentX in my java ant testng project but facing below issue

Tags: java, mongodb, selenium-webdriver, ant, extent

I'm trying to use ExtentX in my java ant testing project but facing the below issue,
but when trying to write results into mongo db I am facing this error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
    FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite beforeSuite
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:711)
        at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:148)
        at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:138)
        at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentX.<init>(ExtentX.java:293)
        at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.x(ExtentReports.java:570)
        at xtent.ExtentManager.getReporter(ExtentManager.java:44)
        at xtent.sample.beforeSuite(sample.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:510)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:211)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:296)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)
        at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)

    SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
    SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
    SKIPPED: intentionalFailure
    SKIPPED: passTest
```

Comment: HI Raghuveer Addagada, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show the relevant bit of code, and describe how you've tried to fix it so far and why you think that hasn't worked?

Comment: Hi Vince Bowdren. i have sorted out the earliler issue now to assign a projectname for report while adding it to extent x. its throwing null poointer exception

Comment: TestNG] Reporter com.qa.pfr.ExtentTestNGIReporterListener@5be6e01c failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.qa.pfr.ExtentTestNGIReporterListener.generateReport(ExtentTestNGIReporterListener.java:98)
 at org.testng.TestNG.generateReports(TestNG.java:1076)
 at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1035)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
 at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is some problem with your `BeforeSuite` method. Can you please paste your code you have written in class where `BeforeSuite` is available.